# developing android custom keyboard i need my custom font on that keyboard as output on edittext

Tags: java, php, android

I have developed an android custom keyboard. I need to use my own font or custom font on keyboard but as output on edittext.
Actually my keyboard is like pop up keyboard that you used when you are typing any message on whatsapp or messanger.
When you clicked on edittext on your phone your keyboard pop up. The keyboard i just try to develop needs some other font and create it. Know i want to use ttf file as keyboard output text like when key press on my keyboard my custom font will appear on edittext.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public final class FontsOverride {

    public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
    String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
        final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            fontAssetName);
        replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
    }

    protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
        final Typeface newTypeface) {
        try {
            final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                    .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
            staticField.setAccessible(true);
            staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and application class too.

```
public final class Application extends android.app.Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", 
            "fonts/shorthandfont.ttf");
        FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", 
            "fonts/shorthandfont.ttf");
    }
}
```

and manifest as

```
<application android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MyInputClass"
        android:label="@string/simple_ime"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
        >
        <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

I need help from you any idea?

Comment: Where is the edittext defined?

Comment: Actually there is no edittext.

Comment: Custom Keyboard for android there is no need of edittext in this because every phone have already edittext you just have to click on it your keyboard pop up. I have an issue while am using my own font on custom keyboard that was developed by me.

Comment: If it's not your `EditText`, you can't expect to get power over choosing what font it'll get.

Comment: Now what should i do?

Comment: how can i change the font of keyboard while i am using keyboardview and keyboard classes to develop my cutom keyboard app